# Python: Extract files and move files

Tags: python, excel, csv, powerbi

I have downloaded a zip file from mailchimp.  The zip file contains folders and subfolders with csv files.  What I would like to do is to write a program that would extract all the .csv files to a single directory, and then convert them to .xlsx files.

Alternatively, if it would just copy or replace the .csv files to the same directories, this is fine.  I want these to be a source for PowerBI.  I have been unable to use the API to successfully integrate with PowerBI.

I have two scripts I have been using, with different problems.  As you can see below, I'm trying to use the script that does successfully convert the .csv files, but get it to iterate through the folders and subfolders.

First script:  The problem is it doesn't iterate over the excel files in folders and subfolders.  It prints the "The current folder is" and simultaneously only converts the .csv files in the /Mailchimp data directory.

```
import shutil
#os.chdir('F:\CRM\Mailchimp data')
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('F:\CRM\Mailchimp data'):
        print("The current folder is " + folderName)
        for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
            workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
            with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                    for c, col in enumerate(row):
                        worksheet.write(r, c, col)
            workbook.close()
```

Second script:  Same issue, it keeps converting the .csv files in the main folder, but will not walk through the other folders and subfolders.

```
entries = os.listdir('F:\CRM\Mailchimp data')
for entry in entries:
            for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
                workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
                worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
                with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
                    reader = csv.reader(f)
                    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                        for c, col in enumerate(row):
                            worksheet.write(r, c, col)
                workbook.close()
```

Comment: why do you use `'.'` in `glob`? `os.walk()` and `os.listdir()` doesn't change active folder and `'.'` always means the same main folder. You should use `folderName` instead `'.'` in `os.path.join(folderName, '*.csv')`. The same with `os.path.join(entry, '*.csv')`

Comment: A few quick noticeable things you can check: 1. protect windows paths with `\ ` in strings by using the `r` prefix before the string literal, otherwise `\t`, `\n` etc. become escape sequences. 2. what @furas said, path joining with "." doesnt do anything, you probably meant something else.